# What is the world's largest publicly accessible air-conditioned space?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, architecture

Living just off the equator, in a place that's hot & humid all year around, I find myself longing for places with pleasant, predictable, climate-controlled environments.  So:

**What is the largest publicly accessible air-conditioned space in the world?**

- Largest by volume (cubic metres)
- Publicly accessible means anybody can enter (entrance fees are OK)
- Air-conditioned means that the space is kept to temperatures *less* than typical ambient outdoor temperatures (so heating alone doesn't count)
- Must be a single enclosed space (building, mall, atrium, dome, greenhouse etc), not just a single air-con plant providing cooling to a number of different buildings

Comment: The Tokyo metro is quite large. Does it count?

Comment: This is fast becoming WorldTrivia.SE.

Comment: Someone should figure out the volume of the world's largest indoor ski resorts.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the Great Mosque of Mecca (the second-largest building in the world after Boeing's Everett factory) is currently being upgraded with air conditioning being added. You can debate whether it's publicly accessible as you might have to convert to Islam first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mosque_of_Mecca

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a travel question.

Comment: Maybe the [West Edmonton Mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Edmonton_Mall).  It's almost 500,000m2, and has some huge vaulted areas - no idea what the total internal volume is, though.

Comment: @choster WorldTriviaAndVisaBans.SE

Comment: I was going to say the Boeing Everett Factory by volume (it's still the largest building in the world by volume and there's a public tour,) but apparently it doesn't have air conditioning, but rather just an air circulation system (and, of course, really big doors that can be opened if it gets hot.)

Comment: @stannius I've [brought this up](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5088/41882) with not much response.  Seems it's an acceptable use of the `factoids` tag.

Comment: Must it be a single uninterrupted space? What if there's a wall dividing the space in half. Into 100 different rooms? What if the walls don't extend to the ceiling (you can in theory climb the walls with ladders? What about different floors connected by an open airwell (escalators)?

Comment: @slebetman Add your answers and let the public decide!

Comment: @Uciebila: the question has the `where-on-earth` tag which invites questions such as this one.

Comment: @Strawberry Shanghai metro would be up there as well if that counts

Comment: @MattDouhan Metro stations may be air-conditioned, but the tunnels are not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would think it is the [Tropical Island Resort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Islands_Resort) in Germany. Apparently it has 5.5 million m³ of volume space. It is kept around 26°C all year around.

Comment: Interesting, but that seems more heated than air-conditioned though?

Comment: @lambshaanxy What's the difference?

Comment: @gerrit: Air conditioning means cooling. Air conditioning was only invented in the middle of the 20th century. Heating has existed for as long as humans have been able to make fire. The tech where there is no difference is called "climate control", not "air conditioning".

Comment: @hippietrail Thank you for the clarification.  In German, "climate control" and "air conditioning" have the same word ("Klimaanlage").

Comment: Current day big space heating and air conditioning are sharing most of the technology, it is not a simple fire anymore.

Comment: @hippietrail Please tell the manufacturer of my car this. I can turn the AC on and set the temperature to 30 degrees+. I live in the UK so I can assure you it never gets that hot outside.

Comment: Not sure what this argument is about, the OP specifically says "heating alone doesn't count".  It doesn't matter what vocabulary you use, if the space can't be cooled lower than the ambient outside temperature, it doesn't count.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I think we just need a confirmation if this place actually does have A/C or not. You'll clearly need to heat this place most of the year, but it is still possible that they'd need to cool the building in the middle of summer, although the cooling effect of all the water might make that unnecessary. I can't find confirmation one way or another, and the fact that it remains at 26C all year doesn't necessarily mean they have A/C, although they may.

Comment: @Darren, that's a bit of a special case -- when you're doing that, your car is actually running the air conditioner to cool the air, then using the engine's waste heat to re-heat it again.  The reason they let you do this seemingly inefficient thing is that cooling and re-heating also drys the air, which makes it extremely effective at defrosting the windows.

Comment: Big buildings sometimes end up needing AC even in surprisingly cool climates, because of the heat production inside.

Comment: @Darren If you set your car to 30 C and enable the AC, your car won't actually run the AC compressor unless the car's cabin actually gets above 30 C (which is possible, even if the outside air temperature never reaches that. Though this requires sunlight, so might not be a problem in the UK. :) ) Unless, of course, your car is running both the AC and the heat, as Nate's comment mentioned.

Comment: As a side note, I see that some of the rooms at Tropical Islands Resort do have air conditioning, but I haven't been able to find anything yet confirming that the entire space does.

Comment: @NuclearWang I don't see why the water in the pools shouldn't count as air condition, if it happens to make the space cooler than ambient on occasion. I don't see why it shouldn't on especially hot summer days.

Comment: @hippietrail Air conditioning is commonly defined as the removal of heat _and moisture_ from a space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_conditioning. This is almost certainly the case in a space with plenty of moisture sources.

Comment: @bdsl I suppose that's reasonable, but it depends on how closely we want to adhere to the definition of A/C as removing heat and moisture. Water-cooled A/C is a thing, but it doesn't work just by flowing water through a warm room. If we accept this as a form of A/C, we might have to include any underground space that naturally has geothermal cooling, like the ~16 million cubic meters of the NYC subway. I think A/C is more than "anything that happens to make the space cooler".

Comment: In NZ at least, it is common to have reversible heat pumps, which can heat your home in the winter and cool it in the summer, with the same mechanism. (At least, to the extent that heat pumps are common in NZ at all)

Comment: From https://www.tropical-islands.de/en/tropical-world/attractions/15-years-of-tropical-islands/  : “Air - At Tropical Islands, the air temperature is 25°C and humidity a pleasant 40 - 60%, perfect conditions for plants from all over the world. There is also under-floor heating in the Lagoon and the Tropical Sea area, so visitors do not get cold feet. A complex climate control and irrigation system guarantees that the various temperature zones are maintained in the Dome”, so it looks as though it has A/C

Comment: It [does get warmer](https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/de/sch%C3%B6nefeld/EDDB/date/2019-7) than 25°C near that location in Germany, so if it is kept at 25°C there is A/C

Answer (score 22):

I have not yet been able to find the volume of the [Iran Mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Mall), in Tehran, but its area is 1.4 million square meters, and it appears to be multi-floor.

Based on a comment by [Neusser](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/49556/neusser), 1.4 million square meters is the total floor area, so I can only count one floor height. At 3 meter height, that would give it a total volume of about 4.2 million cubic meters, 5.6 million cubic meters at 4 meters.

Comment: Even if the entire building was 2m tall, it would have more volume than the current #1 answer of the O2 Arena with 2.79m2.  And I'm sure it's taller than 2m...

Comment: 1.4 million square meters is the total area of all floors! It’s built on area of 317000 square meters. https://www.iranmall.com/en/article/p50-Introducing-Iran-Mall

Comment: Do you have a source for the surface ? The wikipedia page just link to the Mall's website without any citation. Is it really only the surface of indoor floors or does it include exteriors ? Is it really all A/C ?

Comment: 1.4 million sqm is the PLANNED size.  When it was opened a few years ago it was only a fraction of that size.  I'm not sure of it's current size, but I don't believe the entire building is complete yet.

Comment: that's big, Mall of America is I believe about 400,000 M2. (floorspace)

Answer (score 8):

The [O2 arena in London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_O2) is an air condiditoned space of 2.79 million cubic meters. Looking at [Wikipedia's list of largest buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_buildings), this may well be the largest-volume building that is both publicly accessible and air conditioned. There are only 8 buildings larger in volume than the O2, but their main spaces are either not publicly accessible, not air conditioned, or both (unclear about the Tropical Islands Resort mentioned in another answer, but it would seem reasonable to forego air conditioning for an indoor water park located in a cold climate).

Comment: Are you sure the O2 Arena only has airconditioning? It is quite cold in winter in London, I am pretty sure it also needs heating (just like that German sample.)

Comment: @Willeke I'm certain it does have heating too, but I don't see any requirement from the OP that we're looking for an air conditioning-only building - it just can't be heat-only.

Comment: The O2 can hold 20,000 people. That many people will significantly heat the building naturally meaning that the AC will have to be used even during the winter.

Comment: @Burgi To elaborate on "significantly", each person dissipates on average 50W while resting and already double that during moderate activities; so the people in a booked-out O2 arena would produce somewhere between 1 and 4 MW of heat.

Comment: @Willeke - just curious, whyt is that relevant?  the question is about cooling - air con.

Comment: I likely misread that 'only air conditioning' was to be the limit, not combined with heating.

Answer (score 3):

I'll kick off with one:

The [Flower Dome](https://www.gardensbythebay.com.sg/en/attractions/flower-dome/visitor-information.html) at Singapore's Gardens by the Bay is the largest greenhouse in the world as listed in the 2015 Guinness Book of World Records, clocking in at **[195,000㎥](https://www.gardensbythebay.com.sg/en/attractions/flower-dome/facts-and-figures.html)** of space kept to 23-25°C all year around.  For comparison, ambient temperatures in Singapore hover around 30°C.

Comment: There must be 100's of air conditioned sports stadia in the world that are bigger than that. Even just in Singapore,  there's National Stadium.

Comment: Heck, there must be shopping malls in Singapore bigger than that. Do Wisma Atria and Takeshimiya and Orchard MRT count as a single "space"?

Comment: Plaza Singapura is 58,400 m^2 of floor space, at least 3 m high, plus a big atrium. Plus it's connected to an MRT station that must be at least 1 km long.

Comment: @TheProton Feel free to add more answers if you can find figures to back them up!

Answer (score 3):

What about the Vehicle Assembly Building at NASA's Kennedy Space Center (KSC).

https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/facilities/vab.html

The VAB covers 3.25 hectares (8 acres). It is 160 meters (525 ft 10 in) tall, 218 meters (716 ft 6 in) long and 158 meters (518 ft) wide. It encloses **3,664,883 cubic meters** (129,428,000 cubic feet) of space.

The building has at least 40 MW of air conditioning equipment, including 125 ventilatorson the roof supported by four large air handlers (four cylindrical structures west of the building) to keep moisture under control. Air in the building can be completely replaced every hour. The interior volume of the building is so vast that it has its own weather, including "rain clouds form[ing] below the ceiling on very humid days"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Assembly_Building

But I dont know if you really can visit it (https://space.nss.org/you-too-can-visit-the-vehicle-assembly-building/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe stretching the spirit of the question (not man-made, entrance fee ~$3000 USD), but perhaps the [Hang Sơn Đoòng Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_S%C6%A1n_%C4%90o%C3%B2ng) - it has a continuously connected volume of 38.4 million m³.

Comment: Probably doesn't fit the needs of OP's question which is about air-conditioned spaces.  However you're right in that a cave is often cooler than the ambient outside temperature, but its through natural means not A/C.

Comment: @Criggie - That's what I meant by "stretching the spirit of the question" - but it fits OP's rules as written, and OP indicated that they were "looking forward to the inevitable loophole", so I went for it.

Comment: Improvement "Caves are sometimes described as having a natural AC system because their internal temperatures tend to be a lot cooler than the outside air. "   For example, the Australian township of Coober Pedy  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coober_Pedy  where most people live in caves, and there are few AC systems.   I think this is a reasonable answer because it challenges some unstated assumptions in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to mention indoor ski slope, like the biggest [Alpincenter Bottrop](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpincenter_Bottrop), but apparently a ski slope is way smaller than a mall... If the roof is at 4m we stand at a volume of about 77k cubic meters.

Answer (score 0):

Boeing's [Everett Production Facility](http://www.boeing.com/company/about-bca/everett-production-facility.page#/facts) is the largest building in the world by volume at **~13.4m cubic meters**.  It is climate controlled.

At approximately 98 acres, it is larger than Disneyland but smaller than Magic Kingdom.

[Public tours](https://www.boeingfutureofflight.com/) are available for a fee.

Comment: This building does not have air conditioning. The climate is controlled either by opening the doors to cool the building, or turning on the lights to heat the building. There is no way to cool the building below the ambient outdoor temperature, which fails the OP's requirements. See https://blogs.mentor.com/jvandomelen/blog/2010/04/15/the-biggest-building-in-the-world-10-boeing-everett-factory-myths-true-or-false/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the unit of volume referenced. `sq/m` I'm assuming 'cubic meters', but `sq/m` shows the intention of dividing a square by a meter, or '13.4 million squares per meter'.

Comment: @Travis I think it was intended as square meter (m2), an area. But that's supposed to be written as sq m, not sq/m.

Comment: Blatantly fails the question - it's well known to NOT be air conditioned!

Comment: @Doc Well, it's ok if you and the others didn't read the question, totally expected by now.  Still a winner for me!